# Avoid multiple include_directories directives using Cmake

Tags: cmake

I've been assigned to completely run a project using CMake.

Basically, the project has over 20 modules, and for each module i created a CMake file
such as:

```
# Module: CFS
file(
    GLOB_RECURSE
    files
    *.c
    *.cpp
)

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/PEM/cfs")
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/PEM/kernel2")
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
add_library(cfs ${files})
```

kernel2 is another module and has its own CMakeFile.

Now the problem is that a third module: m3 requires headers from cfs (which also require headers from kernel2)

So i basically go with:

```
# Module: m3
file( ... )
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/PEM/cfs")
add_library(m3 ${files})
target_link_library(m3 cfs)
```

Unfortunately this is not enough, kernel2 included files won't be found when i compile unless I add:

```
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/PEM/kernel2")
```

Am I doing it wrong? Perhaps I should also add include files using add_library directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `#include` directives in cfs's headers, then you should use

```
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/PEM/kernel2")
```

It's not the problem of CMake, but how C/C++ compiler works.

For example, you have following header in cfs:

```
#include "kernel2/someclass.h"

class SomeCfsClass
{
private:
    SomeKernelClass kernelObject;
}
```

Now if you wish to instantiate `SomeCfsClass` in your **m3** module, the compiler should know it's size. But knowing it's size is not possible without knowning `SomeKernelClass` definition from kernel2/someclass.h.

This situation can be resolved by storing not the object, but pointer to it inside `SomeCfsClass`:

```
class SomeKernelClass; // forward declare SomeKernelClass

class SomeCfsClass
{
private:
    SomeKernelClass * kernelObject;
}
```

But of course, there are cases, when it's simply impossible to avoid including.

As an alternative, i can suggest to use relative paths in `#include` directives, but this solution is somewhat hackish.

Comment: Either i explained it wrong or got it wrong. But since cfs compiles and outputs a library file, isn't there any way to tell m3 to use that library without including the kernel2 headers?

Comment: If cfs' headers includes kernel2 headers - no. If you wish, i can expand answer with explanation why is it so.